# conditional Combinations and permutations

Tags: combinations, permutation

How do I find the number of combinations of apartments which can be built in a building of n floors, where a large apartment has 2 floors and a small apartment has only 1 floor.

Answer (score 0):

Start from a ground.

You can build 1-floor building with the only way, so `F(1) = 1`.

You can build 2-floor building with two ways as 1+1 and 2,  so `F(2) = 2`.

Look for general approach:
You can build n-floor building making small  apartment on top of n-1 building, or making large apartment on top of n-2 building, so `F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)`

Now implement this logic in code.